# Use of square brackets in backbone routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone and Javascript, and I'd like to use square brackets in my website, but I can't make it work.

So, my url would be like

```
#explore[1]/path
```

I tried with

```
'explore[:sessionId](/*path)': 'showExplorer'
```

with no luck.

Anyone?

Comment: what about regexp as url matcher ? - checkout 'routes' section - http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes

Comment: @Evgeniy thanks, you guided me to the right path!

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to do this by writing a regular expression as follows:

```
 'explore(\[:sessionId\])(/*path)': 'showExplorer'
```